# How to install loki with helm and with a path “/loki” instead of path “/”?

Tags: kubernetes-helm, grafana-loki

I installed loki using helm and configured ingress to to port 3100 and path /loki. Now when I access https://myURL/loki it is giving 404. It seems loki is picking basepath as / instead of /loki.

Is there a way where I can install loki with defining path (key for path)?

Comment: I tried  installing loki with --server.path-prefix=/loki/. But seems there is no configuration in loki charts to handle these.

Comment: In case this is still relevant: Post your `values.yaml` and the chart-version you used (`helm show chart loki/loki`), please. Otherwise it's hard to see where the error could be.